# set type for the key values of Object.entries in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

**Quick task description:**

I have an object of areas and I need to do some processing of those areas
depending on their type using the `areaProcessor` function. Also, only 'toCreate' and 'toRemove' types of areas should be processed.

```
type AreaType = 'toCreate' | 'toRemove' | 'toUpdate';

const areas: AreaType = { toCreate: [], toUpdate: [], toRemove: [] };

const areaProcessor = (areaType: AreaType, gf: any): any => {};

Object.entries(areas)
      .filter(([areaType, _]) => areaType === 'toCreate' || areaType === 'toRemove')
      .flatMap(([areaType, gf]) => areaProcessor(areaType, gf));
```

**Problem:**

The problem here is that typescript throws a type error for `areaProcessor`:

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"toCreate" | "toRemove"'.

Obviously, it's because in the `flatMap` function `areaType` is of type `string`, but I'd like it to be of type

```
type AreaType = 'toCreate' | 'toRemove' | 'toUpdate';
```

**Question:**

How do I do the conversion then?

**P.S.**

I used `any` just to avoid introducing new, irrelevant types.

Comment: Can you fix the syntax errors in your code and provide a definition for `areas`?

Comment: Here's the [solution](https://tsplay.dev/mL2dZw), but since your code is incomplete/has errors, I don't know if this works in your actual code.

Comment: @caTS Sorry, I fixed the errors.

Comment: @caTS Please post that as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.entries` will give you "wider" types than what you would expect (because it could return keys that don't exist in the type), but you can ignore this by making your own type:

```
type Entries<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: [key: K, value: T[K]];
}[keyof T][];
```

Then we have to cast to this and use a type predicate to narrow the entries:

```
(Object.entries(obj) as Entries<typeof obj>)
    .filter((pair): pair is [AreaType, typeof pair[1]] => pair[0] === "toCreate" || pair[0] === "toRemove")
    .flatMap(([areaType, gf]) => areaProcessor(areaType, gf)); // OK
```

After we narrow the entries, it is now OK to pass `areaType` to `areaProcessor`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ssl=13&ssc=63&pln=10&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggThAhgFXNAvFARMA9gYQUWAiygB9s8AlCAW1wDdSBuAKDYGNcA7AZ2BRcAIwBWUTAG8oeQkhIAuKAG0AugBoZuAKpgAJsQhK1mmvSZGVqqAF92XXgKiIiABTi5OEPn1xwJUAAULkiokErwoWiaAOYAZkqIPCAAlInJEgB8UJJ2HKCQUACiPMBwAJbeADzI2VJsUI0qANJQ5TxQANYQILhxUMiqxt0gSs2ajIgANgCulsjKzaqq7DbKI30Dqmr2gQDyYhCcwAB0EKUV3oEioinOfMUXlXxVBRCbN5kpDU0nceVTEhwQKBMCIcpwNJQMEQtoPZSRFDRGRoTYwuDKACMyyy0PBGIADNZ0CSqAQiCQyORKOjlESJKScLhaAxmFhvk0oH8psQALKIMAg5QhJGQWJxVR3dDZEXuTzeXzAkVhCDilIpdhAA)

Comment: Thank you. And one more question. The filter part could be written like so, right? `.filter(([areaType, _]) => areaType === 'toCreate' || zoneType === 'toRemove')`
I've checked, the `areaType` is inferred.

Comment: @Alex Doesn't seem to work... https://tsplay.dev/WvG3Mw

Comment: Well it's because the code in the playground is a little obsolete, I made some edits after you asked me to, and also extended the `AreaType` type which is is declared as follows: `type AreaType = 'toCreate' | 'toRemove' | 'toUpdate';`, with this type it works.

Comment: I decided not to ask this question here, cos it would be against the community guidelines. So I made it into a a separate question. Could you please have a look?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74221788/less-memory-intensive-typescript-solution-for-mapping